# Associate prediction task to a graph autoencoder (GAE)

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, graph-theory

I have been reading about *graph autoencoders* and was wondering if it might be a reasonable idea trying to associate to the unsupervised setting which produces some best low-dimensional representation of nodes in the graph, a supervised one where I immediately after use the graph to predict some property associated to it.. Does this make any sense? Has anybody done something similar already?